Why do the Docs say "5V" but after I buy one, I'm expected to buy a custom power supply?
I believe the rpi was "redesigned" so it  would NOT work on a cell phone charger, like it's touted. Anybody else irritated with the manufacturer over this?

your belief may be based on a misunderstanfing ... please do some research about power supplies ... there is more to a power supply than just the output voltage rating ... what are the specifications of the power supply are you expected to buy? ... what are the specifications of a cheap cell phone power supply? ... note: a cell phone charger is built into the phone

redesigned implies at once stage it could, but now it can't. That's a tin foil conspiracy theory right there

Whats the question

You do not know how power supplies work.  Cell phone chargers are designed for recharging batteries in devices that have batteries.  That is a very significant layer of electronics: The device is powered from the battery, not the charger.  The Pi does not have a battery, and live electronics demand sharp fluctuations in current that are not required (or perhaps even desirable) in a supply intended for recharging batteries.  If you have a set-top box at home, it is probably 5V and will demonstrate the same principle if you plug it into your phone charger.

The Pi was never designed to use a charger. The requirement was for 5V±5% which is the USB spec.
Early phones almost universally used a simple 5V 1A supply for charging; indeed I can use an Apple 5W supply to run all my Pi up to Pi3+, but once they included WiFi and increased the USB current capacity 1A is no longer sufficient. (You can now draw 1.2A from USB ports - obviously not if using a 5W supply.)
What changed was the need for phones to have higher current so a new standard was introduced to allow voltages as low as 3.3V for phone chargers which DEFINITELY won't run a Pi.
NOTE I can run my Pi4 & Pi5 with a Apple 20W USB-C Power Adapter and this should be true of most USC-C power supplies which support USB-PD.
